# What are the directories to include in the .gitignore when I use Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

What directories should I avoid pushing to GitHub for a Laravel Nova application (.gitignore)? Just the /nova directory? I suppose these directories should push to GitHub, and I will not affect the Laravel Nova Licenses, am I right?

- /app/nova
- /public/vendor/nova
- /resources/lang/vendor/nova
- /resources/views/vendor/nova

Comment: I just do `/nova`. That's the most important right?